# functional inheritance and toString override in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, closures

Using a functional constructor (as outlined in **JavaScript: The Good Parts** - Crockford) I am trying to override toString. Here is an example:

```
var point = function(x, y) {
    var x = x || 0;
    var y = y || 0;
    var that = {};

    that.getx = function() {
        return x;
    };
    that.toString = function() {
        return '(' + x + ', ' + y + ')';
    };
    return that;
}
```

So given:

```
var point1 = point(1,1);
console.log(point1);
```

I would like to see (1, 1) on the console. Instead I get a listing of the point constructor.

```
console.log(point1.toString());
```

works but is not what I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the broken `toString` declaration a typo, or is that in your actual code?

Comment: No. `console.log` does not automatically stringify its arguments, and there's no reason to so. Just use `console.log(String(point1))` if you want your custom string representation instead of the standard introspection format.

Comment: That was a typo. Thanks. You are correct if I do console.log(''+point1); it works as expected.